# Sveltekit endpoint issues for making contact form

Tags: javascript, svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

I'm making a contact form but am getting an error of
`POST http://localhost:3000/contact.json 500 (Internal Server Error)` at `contactform.svelte:5`.
Here's what `contactform.svelte` is:

```html
<script>
    const submitForm = async(data) => {
        const formData = new FormData(data.currentTarget);

        const res = await fetch("contact.json", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        });
    };
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={submitForm}>
    <div>
        <label for="">
            What's your name?
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="">
            What's your Email or Phone #?
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <input type="text" name="phone">

        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="">
            What would you like to tell us?
            <input type="text" name="message">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

In my terminal i have another error of:

```sh
To access the request body use the text/json/arrayBuffer/formData methods, e.g. `body = await request.json()`. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3384 for details
Error: To access the request body use the text/json/arrayBuffer/formData methods, e.g. `body = await request.json()`. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3384 for details
    at Object.get (file:///C:/Users/chian/Desktop/site/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:2662:10)
    at post (C:\Users\chian\Desktop\site\src\routes\contact.json.js:2:26)
    at render_endpoint (file:///C:/Users/chian/Desktop/site/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:157:25)
    at resolve (file:///C:/Users/chian/Desktop/site/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:2743:17)
    at async respond (file:///C:/Users/chian/Desktop/site/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:2688:20)
    at async file:///C:/Users/chian/Desktop/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:299:24
```

Here's contact.json.js:

```js
export const post = async(request) => {
    const name = request.body.get("name");
    const email = request.body.get("email");
    const phone = request.body.get("phone");
    const message = request.body.get("message");

    const res = await fetch(`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1AFIpQLSfx-JOL3dNrjWL-raYmT4ay_TIT6xfFVBXaZ5R_m8RB-G_Ang/formResponse?usp=pp_url&entry.1204260556=${name}&entry.1586743587=${email}&entry.807821212=${phone}&entry.1059243301=${message}&submit=Submit`);

    console.log(res);
};
```

I followed a tutorial writing this and to be completely honest don't grasp everything yet as I'm new to backend and svelte in general and hope fixing this problem can get me some insight into how everything works. Let me know if y'all have any idea of how to solve this.

Comment: To "grasp" how to process Sveltekit SSR forms with or without javascript on the client and use endpoints, here's a nice intro: https://codechips.me/sveltekit-ssr-forms/

Answer (score 6):

Since you are passing formData you should use the correct methods:

```js
const data = await request.formData();
const name = data.get("name");
```

alternatively you can create an object from the formData:

```js
const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
console.log(data.name);
```