# Bcrypt Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, number when sending post request through frontend

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm fairly new to nodejs and I'm struggling with this bcrypt error right now. When I use postman to send the post request(raw-data) it works without any errors, but when I send the request through form-data or from frontend, it will throw an error:

```
nextTick(callback.bind(this, Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof salt))));
                                             ^
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, number
```

here is what my code looks like:

```js
//backend authcontroller

export const signUpLogic = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    //
    const result = userSchema.safeParse({
      username,
      email,
      password: String(hashedPassword),
    });
    //
    res.status(200).json(result);
  }cath(err){
//some error handling
}
```

in my frontend:

```html
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/sign-up" method="post">
    <!-- some input fields here-->
    </form>
```

How can I fix this error?

ps: about the form-data error I tried to use `body-parser` as the middleware but the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The body parser middle-ware has to be configured like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

if you are using the latest version of express:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
```

This should remove the error that is caused because the server is not able to parse form data.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the error still remains.

Comment: are you getting username, email, password  in the req.body?

Comment: nope. In the postman it shows 'Could not get response' and in the terminal it shows the same error as before.

Comment: are you using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()); app.use(bodyParser.json());` both parsers in your server?

Comment: yep and `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))`, i tried both with and without this line of code but the result is still the same.

Comment: you have to use them together for it to work from postman and html page

Comment: yes, I did use them together but it still shows the error in the terminal. I realised when I submit the form my frontend URL changed from `localhost://5173/sig-up` to `localhost:3000/sig-up` and says localhost didn't send any data. Is that where the problem is?

Comment: How is your front and backend hosted?

Comment: my backend is just typical nodejs/express app(`app.listen(3000,()=>{})`). And my frontend I use sveltekit which by default lives on port 5173. Is that what you mean?

Comment: it is a problem with the way sveltekit works. refer to this question and make changes accordingly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790298/sveltekit-endpoint-issues-for-making-contact-form